# How to prettify json with jq given a string with escaped double quotes

Tags: json, jq

I would like to pretty print a json string I copied from an API call which contains escaped double quotes.

Similar to this:

```
"{\"name\":\"Hans\", \"Hobbies\":[\"Car\",\"Swimming\"]}"
```

However when I execute `pbpaste | jq "."`  the result is not changed and is still in one line.

I guess the problem are the escaped double quotes, but I don't know how to tell `jq` to remove them if possible, or any other workaround.

Comment: you are right, I updated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a JSON string which happens to contain a JSON object. You can decode the contents of the string with the `fromjson` function.

```
$ pbpaste | jq "."
"{\"name\":\"Hans\", \"Hobbies\":[\"Car\",\"Swimming\"]}"
$ pbpaste | jq "fromjson"
{
  "name": "Hans",
  "Hobbies": [
    "Car",
    "Swimming"
  ]
}
```